# IE cannot redirect wamp server 404 error page

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I install a wampserver on my pc and i want to redirect a Http 404 Not Found error page to my style page but it not work properly in IE 9.0

if i give the file that not in wamp server, it shows the wamp server error page like this in firefox, safari

[image: In firefox, safari]

But in IE the same thing show like this

[image: But in IE]

how can i make this same for all browser. Can anyone help me.

I use .htaccess file and httpd.config file to change the redirection but it not work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a .htaccess file and create your custom redirects. See this

http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/

Comment: However i use the .htaccess file and also httpd.config file to redirect a page it redirect correctly in firefox,safari but not in IE. Thats why i ask this question...